# Configuring ui-grid using webpack

Tags: angularjs, webpack, ui-grid

I am new to Webpack and node. Need help in configuring ui-grid.

I wanted to bundle angular using webpack, So I installed angular using npm and after installing I could see index.js file inside angular folder in node_modules, which actually export angular module. To include angular module I include following line in entry file of webpack.

`const angular = require('angular');`

And it works fine. Now I am trying to do same thing for ui-grid but I could not find index.js file there which actually imports ui-grid module.

Please provide pointers about how to include ui-grid and what is the concept of index.js.